# Graceful ramp down of user load in locust

Tags: performance-testing, locust

Is there a way to do graceful ramp down of my user load while running load tests using locust framework ?

For e.g. using the below command -

[image]

I want to run a single user for a time period of 5 minutes in a loop, but here what happens is that the last iteration end abruptly with lets say 5 requests on some of the tasks and 4 on some others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a new flag (developed by yours truly :) called `--stop-timeout` that will make locust wait for the users to complete (up to the specified time span)

There is (as of now) no way to do actual ramp down (gradually reducing the load by shutting down users over time), but hopefully this is enough for you. Such a feature might be added at a later time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and for adding this feature !  Does this flag take time in seconds as an input ?

Comment: Yes! use "locust --help" for more info!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Shape that allows you to specify how many user should be present at any time of the test.

This is explained there: https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/1505